# Javascript Sum values of a list using map/reduce

Tags: javascript, sum

I am very new to java and I need to use map and reduce functions. I made a lot of search but couldn't find a solution. Here is my data:

```
var lehighCounty = {
  name: "Lehigh County",
  population: 372492,
};

var philiCounty = {
  name: "Philadelphia County",
  population: 1596865,
};

var franklinCounty = {
  name: "Franklin County",
  population: 155592,
};

var northamptonCounty = {
  name: "Northampton County",
  population: 311359,
};


var pennCounties = [
  lehighCounty, philiCounty, franklinCounty, northamptonCounty
];

print(pennCounties);
```

Using the code below, I can extract the population values of each object.

```
var population = pennCounties.map(function(county) {
return county.population; }); 
print(population);


[372492,1596865,155592,311359]
```

My main aim is to sum of each value using the `reduce` . I intended to apply the code below but I couldn't achieve.

```
List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(population);
Integer sum = integers.stream()
  .reduce(0, (a, b) -> a + b);
```

Comment: Is this Java or JavaScript?

Comment: it is javascript, my bad.

Comment: FYI, the last code snippet you have is for the Java programming language, not for Javascript. Therefore it won't run in javascript (e.g. in the browser or nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) like so:

```js
let lehighCounty={name:"Lehigh County",population:372492},philiCounty={name:"Philadelphia County",population:1596865},franklinCounty={name:"Franklin County",population:155592},northamptonCounty={name:"Northampton County",population:311359},pennCounties=[lehighCounty,philiCounty,franklinCounty,northamptonCounty];
let sum = pennCounties.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.population, 0);
console.log(sum);
```